# How many times the code of a local function is created? Only once or anytime the parent function is called?

Tags: c#, local-functions

Modern C# supported definition of nested functions. For example:

```
public bool Test(params int[] args) {
    bool isNumberValid(int i) {
        return i > 0;
   }
   foreach(var n in args) {
      if(!isNumberValid(n)) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

I wrote the above example only as a test case scenario and it doesn't matter if it can be refactored. Now the question is, how many times is the `isNumberValid` function created? Is it created only once in such a way that it is moved outside the parent function block by the compiler? or is it created over over at runtime anytime the parent function is invoked (scoped under the parent stack)?

Comment: Once. The compiler generates a static method to represent this. Even if the method had to close over variables declared outside, the compiler passes them by reference.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: how about an Action or Function delegate, are they treated the same by the compiler? In other words does the compiler handle nested functions and delegates differently?

Comment: Delegates are reference types and are instantiated / placed on the heap, or are you referring to anonymous functions (e.g. lambda expressions)?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: Yes exactly, I meant lambda expression and not exactly delegates.

Comment: No, for an anonymous function, the compiler generates a class with a method representing that function. In the case that the function does not require a closure, the compiler can optimise the generated class to be a singleton, otherwise a new instance of that class is created each time the method needs to be invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a decompiler to inspect the output, you'll see something like this:

```
public bool Test(params int[] args)
{
    bool flag;
    int[] numArray = args;
    int num = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (num >= (int)numArray.Length)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (Program.<Test>g__isNumberValid|1_0(numArray[num]))
        {
            num++;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

This shows that it has been compiled to a separate method, and is compiled only once.

Also note that for such a small local function in this example, the chances are that (for release mode builds) the JIT compiler will inline the function so that there isn't even a function call made for it.

Comment: Well that technically means, it becomes a member of its class, is that correct?

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Yes, it's a static member of the enclosing class.

Comment: Well, it is interesting, because at compile time we cannot acquire a reference to that function directly via its class, but if running the code dynamically, using reflection for example, that would be possible.

Comment: Technically you could do that, but the implementation is undefined and you couldn't rely on that working.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the generated MSIL code from ILSpy.

As we see, the local method is converted as being like any instance method of the current class and the code only exists once.

Thus the compiler "refactor" itself.

C# local methods are not like C and C ++ [inline functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) whose code is repeated according to usage.

Local methods allow to refactor the code and to create a more clean code while disallowing the call from the exterior of the method containing them, to segregate processings and/or to call them several times.

There is also previously available the local lambdas using [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action) and [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.func-1).

Also the [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), being the ancestor of all.

[Local functions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)

```
.method public hidebysig static bool Test (int32[] args) cil managed 
{
    .param [1]
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.ParamArrayAttribute::.ctor() = (01 00 00 00)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32[],
        [1] int32,
        [2] int32 n,
        [3] bool,
        [4] bool
    )

    //  foreach (int i2 in args)
    //  {
    //      if (!isNumberValid(i2))
    //      {
    //          return false;
    //      }
    //  }
    IL_0003: ldarg.0
    // (no C# code)
    IL_0004: stloc.0
    IL_0005: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0006: stloc.1
    IL_0007: br.s IL_0026
    // loop start (head: IL_0026)
        IL_0009: ldloc.0
        IL_000a: ldloc.1
        IL_000b: ldelem.i4
        IL_000c: stloc.2
        // if (!isNumberValid(i2))
        IL_000e: ldloc.2
```

```
>>>>>>>>>>
        IL_000f: call bool ConsoleApp.Program::'<Test>g__isNumberValid|30_0'(int32)
>>>>>>>>>>
```

```
        IL_0014: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0015: ceq
        IL_0017: stloc.3
        IL_0018: ldloc.3
        // (no C# code)
        IL_0019: brfalse.s IL_0021

        // return false;
        IL_001c: ldc.i4.0
        IL_001d: stloc.s 4
        // (no C# code)
        IL_001f: br.s IL_0031

        IL_0022: ldloc.1
        IL_0023: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0024: add
        IL_0025: stloc.1

        IL_0026: ldloc.1
        IL_0027: ldloc.0
        IL_0028: ldlen
        IL_0029: conv.i4
        IL_002a: blt.s IL_0009
    // end loop

    // return true;
    IL_002c: ldc.i4.1
    IL_002d: stloc.s 4
    // (no C# code)
    IL_002f: br.s IL_0031

    IL_0031: ldloc.s 4
    IL_0033: ret
} // end of method Program::Test
```

Here is the local method now being a class method:

```
.method assembly hidebysig static bool '<Test>g__isNumberValid|30_0' (int32 i) cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor()
      = (01 00 00 00)
    // Method begins at RVA 0x342c
    // Code size 10 (0xa)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] bool
    )

    // return i > 0;
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0003: cgt
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    // (no C# code)
    IL_0006: br.s IL_0008

    IL_0008: ldloc.0
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method Program::'<Test>g__isNumberValid|30_0'
```